# Joint Density of two Cauchy Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, density-function

$\mathbf {Problem:}$ If $X, Y, Z$ are i.i.d. from **standard normal**, find the **joint density** of
$W=X/Y$ and $V=Y /Z$?

$\mathbf {Attempt:}$ All I know is $W=X/Y$ and $V=Y /Z$ both follows **Cauchy Distribution**. But how do I find out the joint density of $W$ and $V$? I think $W$ and $Z$ are not independent, so can't use $$ f_{W,V}(w,v) = f_{W}(w) \cdot f_V(v)$$ Where $f$ denote density.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There could be an easier way but you could try applying the usual change of variables technique.

Joint density of $(X,Y,Z)$ is $$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\qquad,\,(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$$

Transform $(X,Y,Z)\to(U,V,W)$ such that $$U=\frac{X}{Y},\quad V=\frac{Y}{Z},\quad W=Z$$

We have the inverse solutions $$x=uvw,\quad y=vw,\quad z=w$$

Then $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\implies (u,v,w)\in\mathbb R^3$.

A quick calculation gives the absolute value of Jacobian as $|J|=|v|w^2$.

So the joint density of $(U,V,W)$ is $$f_{U,V,W}(u,v,w)=\frac{|v|w^2}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3}e^{-\frac{w^2}{2}(u^2v^2+v^2+1)}\qquad,\,(u,v,w)\in\mathbb R^3$$

Integrating over $w$ you get the joint pdf of $(U,V)$ as

\begin{align}
f_{U,V}(u,v)&=\frac{|v|}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3}\int_{\mathbb R}w^2e^{-\frac{w^2}{2}(u^2v^2+v^2+1)}\,dw
\\&=\frac{2|v|}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3}\int_0^\infty w^2e^{-\frac{w^2}{2}(u^2v^2+v^2+1)}\,dw
\\&=\frac{|v|}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3}\int_0^\infty\sqrt{t}e^{-\alpha t}\,dt\qquad\left[w^2=t;\quad (u^2v^2+v^2+1)/2=\alpha\right]
\\&=\frac{|v|}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3}\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\alpha^{3/2}}
\end{align}

So finally,

$$f_{U,V}(u,v)=\frac{|v|}{2\pi(u^2v^2+v^2+1)^{3/2}}\qquad,\,(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2$$

[Integrating](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%20%20Abs%5Bv%5D%2F(2%20Pi%20(u%5E2%20v%5E2%20%2B%20v%5E2%20%2B%201)%5E(3%2F2)),%20%7Bu,%20-Infinity,%20Infinity%7D,%20%7Bv,%20-Infinity,%20Infinity%7D%5D) this over the support yields $1$, so looks like this is the correct density.

Comment: Just got struck integrating the density to get 1. Got something like $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dz}{(zu^2+z+1)^{3/2}}$ after substituting $z=v^2$ .

Comment: @RATNODEEPBAIN Well, I used software to verify that. Didn't do it myself.

Comment: Oh! Can you name the software.

Comment: @RATNODEEPBAIN https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B++Abs%5Bv%5D%2F(2+Pi+(u%5E2+v%5E2+%2B+v%5E2+%2B+1)%5E(3%2F2)),+%7Bu,+-Infinity,+Infinity%7D,+%7Bv,+-Infinity,+Infinity%7D%5D